# How do you add a subtotal column (ordered quantity x standard price) to this SQL

Tags: sql

I have the following sample data here just wondering how to add a subtotal column (standard price x quantity ordered) to the SQL query

Current query is "SELECT product_description, ordered_quantity, standard_price from m_order_line join m_product using (product_id) where order_id = 1006;"

Image:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/7r9yW.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just multiply the columns:

```
 SELECT product_description, ordered_quantity, standard_price, (ordered_quantity * standard_price) as subtotal
 from m_order_line join m_product using (product_id) 
 where order_id = 1006
 order by (ordered_quantity * standard_price)
```